# Can I undo red choices?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-online

I just chose to do a red option in ESO and am already regretting it. Is there any way to go back and change my decision? I haven't finished the quest yet. Will quitting the quest and doing it again change things?

Comment: AFAIK, yes, restarting will allow you to change.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to undo a red choice, is to **abandon** the quest and restart it from the beginning.

Comment: Unfortunately this means for quests that are over, choice is over